# MYSQL I want to return a NULL value not empty

Tags: mysql

I've a table `'mol_source'` with two columns : `id(int)` and `src_compound_id(varchar)`

I want to get the id of a line where the `src_compound_id` is equal to an variable called : `$src_compound_id_cutted`.

This is the query :

```
get_id=$(echo mysql --login-path=local -N -D uni -e "select id from mol_source where src_compound_id='$src_compound_id_cutted'")
```

I would like if the returned value is empty because it does not find the id, returns `NULL` and not an empty field. I want te replace the empty return by an `NULL` value.

Any ideas? 
i tried to find some solutions on stack but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when id=' ' then null end 
from mol_source where src_compound_id='$src_compound_id_cutted'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NULLIF`:

`SELECT NULLIF(id, 0) as yourvariable FROM mol_source where src_compound_id='$src_compound_id_cutted'`